# Как правильно должен быть реализован Spring Hateoas?

Tags: java, spring, rest

У меня есть RESTful API, в котором я хочу реализовать гипермедию с помощью Spring Hateoas. Для всех ресурсов я уже сделал эту поддержку, но есть следующая проблема: при отправке `GET /` запроса что я должен возвращать клиенту? Вопрос касается чисто hypermedia, а не конкретной реализации API. Можете поделится ресурсами, статьями или советами, как правильно строить такие сервисы.